# Difference between #include<QObject> and #include<qobject.h>

Tags: c++, qt

Is there any difference between using `#include< QObject >` and `#include< qobject.h >` ?

Both of these seem to work, so there must be some reason as to why `#include< QObject >` is preferred?

Answer (score 2):

Any standard Qt header file without .h extension is guaranteed to be correct with next Qt versions and other platforms, like a standard interface header. And qobject.h as well as other Qt header files with .h extension are just implementation headers that may eventually not work for you.

```
Use 
    #include <QObject>
and not
    #include <qobject.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

They are the same from a user's point of view (I believe Qt added both for convenience, but don't quote me on that).

However, it's preferred to write `#include <QObject>`, because *typically* people use quotes when including header files, and brackets when including "builtin" files (C++ STL, Qt builtins, etc.).

In most situations, the two are interchangeable. However, using the brackets (with most compilers) will search first for system headers, then for header files in the local directory, while the quotes will typically search in the local directory first.

Note that this is compiler dependent.

For example, this is how you typically see includes:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

#include "foreignlibrary.h"
```

Comment: The question is not about _quotes_ or _brackets_, both of the OP’s examples do include brackets.

Comment: I thought I addressed that-- and yet somehow it never went from my mind to the answer. My fault.

Answer (score 1):

The file `Qt/include/QtCore/QObject` contains just:

```
#include "qobject.h"
```

So both ways are functionally equal. From the perspective of C++ preprocessor, including `QObject` is one more indirection level. However, this doesn’t make a big difference with modern computers.

Qt developers encourage us to `#include <QObject>`. You should always prefer the documented way over the undocumented one as undocumented features may divert in future versions.

Comment: So there is no actual difference between the two? 
And is this in some way related to pre-compiled headers?

Comment: There is no actual difference **in the current version**. I’m not experienced in the field of pre-compiled headers and I’d just recommend _the documented way_ for the second time.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the way that is documented and guaranteed to work is:

```
#include <QClass>
```

Any other way of including Qt class headers can break with any future release of Qt. It doesn't matter that it works *now*. Qt maintainers are free to break your code if you don't follow the rules.

```
// W R O N G
#include <QtCore/QClass>
#include <qclass.h>
```

The following, though, is correct and is a simple way of including an entire module's worth of declarations, including dependent modules:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
```